# Domain Name and IP Ranges of Mirror API

Tags: google-mirror-api

> The Mirror API allows you to subscribe to notifications that are sent
>   when the user takes specific actions on a Timeline Item or when the
>   user location has been updated. When you subscribe to a notification,
>   you provide a callback URL that processes the notification.

What are `Mirror API`'s **domain name** and **ip ranges** when it comes to my notifyCallback url to pass me notifications from glass?

It is important because I have to allow its ips at my firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I allowed this ip range for Google at my firewall and now I can get requests from `Mirror API:`

> 66.249.80.0 / 255.255.240.0